# Darktable: how to save export account?

Tags: darktable

DT 2.2.5. How to save "export selected" account (facebook/google/flickr) credentials?
fb/google works for me but every time I'm restarting DT I have to go thru authentication process again. Settings->core options->password storage is set to libsecret and the library itself is installed according to synaptic.
Thanks!